# LINQ query with multiple properties, some of which are null

Tags: c#, linq

I've created a LINQ query using C# in .NET 4.5 framework.

The query narrows down the list by comparing a string `FilterInput` to multiple properties, all of type string:

```
tempList = tempList.FindAll(w =>
    w.Number.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.SN.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.Model.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.Location.Contains(FilterInput));
```

So, if `FilterInput` is "ABC", it will include (as a few possible examples):

- w.Number == "ABCD"
- w.SN == "01234ABC"
- w.Model == "ABC"
- w.Location == "ABC Co Incorporated"

Everything goes well, until the query runs across property that contains a `null` for a string property:

- w.SN == `null`
  (please note if w.SN == "null" this isn't the same problem, and doesn't throw the same error)

Is there any way to bypass `null` properties in this statement, without refactoring my properties for `w`?

By the way, I haven't found anything yet on MSDN's helpful site "[how to: write LINQ queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx)"...

Comment: If you're using `FindAll` then you're not using LINQ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `w.SN != null &&`:

```
tempList = tempList.FindAll(w =>
    w.Number.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.SN !=null && w.SN.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.Model.Contains(FilterInput) ||
    w.Location.Contains(FilterInput));
```

You need to add similar checks if other parameters (`w.Number`, `w.Model`, `w.Location`) can be `null` too.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the number of class properties:

for an example:

```
public class test
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
    public int p4 { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
test t1 = new test
{
    p1 = null,
    p2 = "test1",
    p3 = "test2",
    p4 = 0
};
test t2 = new test
{
    p1 = "test1",
    p2 = "test2",
    p3 = "test3",
    p4 = 0
};
test t3 = new test
{
    p1 = "test1",
    p2 = "tst2",
    p3 = "test3",
    p4 = 0
};

string filterInput = "test";
var testStringProperties = typeof(test)
                           .GetProperties()
                           .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
var a1 = testStringProperties.All(p =>
{
    string tempValue = (string)p.GetValue(t1);
    return tempValue != null && tempValue.Contains(filterInput);
});
var a2 = testStringProperties.All(p =>
{
    string tempValue = (string)p.GetValue(t2);
    return tempValue != null && tempValue.Contains(filterInput);
});
var a3 = testStringProperties.All(p =>
{
    string tempValue = (string)p.GetValue(t3);
    return tempValue != null && tempValue.Contains(filterInput);
});
//a1=false
//a2=true
//a3=false
```